# iOS 7 Height of TableView increase Under TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Im trying port my app to iOS7, but the height of my TableView increases in ios 7 while it is correct in ios 6. Due to which last row (cell) is almost half under the tab bar.

Im searching a lot for it, but i dont find any solution. Can anyone help me?

[image: The error is shown in the blow screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html)

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Use `edgesForExtendedLayout` to specify which edges of a view should be extended, regardless of bar translucency. By default, the value of this property is `UIRectEdgeAll`.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars)]) {
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
}
```

If your design uses opaque bars, refine `edgesForExtendedLayout` by also setting the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property to `NO`.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)]) {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

If you don’t want a scroll view’s content insets to be automatically adjusted, set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`.

You can also set `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`. They indicate the location of the top or bottom bar edges in a view controller’s view. If bars should overlap the top or bottom of a view, you can use Interface Builder to position the view relative to the bar by creating constraints to the bottom of `topLayoutGuide` or to the top of `bottomLayoutGuide`.

Moreover, you can also make adjustments in Interface builder.

[image]

And if you are not using autolayout, you can set the deltas for iOS6/7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Storyboard, in Utilities of your UIViewController open "Attributes inspector"

[image]

"Under Top Bars" is ticked?

Comment: Yes Zhans it is exactly according to your screenshot